# Python: Replace multiple old values to new value Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, str-replace

I've been searching around for a while now, but I can't seem to find the answer to this small problem.

I have this code to make a function for replace values:

```
df = {'Name':['al', 'el', 'naila', 'dori','jlo'],
    'living':['Alvando','Georgia GG','Newyork NY','Indiana IN','Florida FL'],
    'sample2':['malang','kaltim','ambon','jepara','sragen'],
    'output':['KOTA','KAB','WILAYAH','KAB','DAERAH']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df = df.replace(['KOTA', 'WILAYAH', 'DAERAH'], 0)
df = df.replace('KAB', 1)
```

But I am actually expecting this output with the simple code that doesn't repeat replace

```
    Name    living      sample2   output
0   al     Alvando      malang     0
1   el     Georgia GG   kaltim     1
2   naila  Newyork NY   ambon      0
3   dori   Indiana IN   jepara     1
4   jlo    Florida FL   sragen     0
```

I've tried using np.where but it doesn't give the desired result. all results display 0, but the original value is 1

```
df['output'] = pd.DataFrame({'output':np.where(df == "KAB", 1, 0).reshape(-1, )})
```

Comment: Does this work for you? `df = df.replace(['KOTA', 'WILAYAH', 'DAERAH'], 0).replace('KAB', 1)`

Comment: OMG broo thank youu. but there is something strange, I've tried this method but it didn't work. but now after i try again it works. why?

Comment: I actually have no idea! I actually copied and ran your code and it worked for me. I'll post an answer real quick :)

Answer (score 2):

This code *should* work for you:

```
df = df.replace(['KOTA', 'WILAYAH', 'DAERAH'], 0).replace('KAB', 1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    Name      living sample2  output
0     al     Alvando  malang       0
1     el  Georgia GG  kaltim       1
2  naila  Newyork NY   ambon       0
3   dori  Indiana IN  jepara       1
4    jlo  Florida FL  sragen       0
```

Comment: @Niken see my comment above, on the question.